# category widget in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, widget, categories

I have about 2000 video post to be posted. and lot many no. of categories for those videos.

I just do not want the category list to keep growing on and making my page lengthier. Could anyone suggest me a plugin or a solution for this. the normal widget look for category is what i don't want.

It should show major categories and when I click on them should show their sub categories and must close when I click again.
Can I find such widget?

**HELP Please**

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple:

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/jquery-categories-list/
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/collapsing-categories/

Try searching the plugin repository for "collapsing categories".